# CSS3 skew all corners

Tags: css, transform, skew

I'm trying to skew my menu items like this:

[image]

I've found a few solution that will let me skew all 4 corners but they use a border-top solution whilst I need to use a background-image solution because of the gradient.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more what you mean... are you trying to skew the inner box while keeping the borders straight? Also, posting some code would be helpful too so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to move each corner around freely, but you can combine `skew` with `rotate` and `transform-origin` to create a lot of different effects. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pv5h0oee/) of something similar to the picture you shared.

If you need something more intricate, it'd likely be best to use SVG.

Answer (score 1):

You can build it with a separate gradient for each zone

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(6deg, blue 19%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(80deg, green 12%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(175deg, red 18%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(275deg, yellow 18%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(6deg, lightblue 21%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(80deg, lightgreen 13%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(175deg, lightcoral 21%, transparent 10%),
        linear-gradient(275deg, lightyellow 19%, transparent 10%);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4dgr4v2/)

Comment: Upvote for the always clever answer, but this is purely visual which I don't think is exactly what the OP was looking for

Comment: @ZachSaucier May be you are right.. I thought that the light blue was part of the div, but it could be background now that I think about it. Some questions are really confuse.